# Pull PHP data using Arduino Ethernet

Tags: http, arduino

I would like to pull data from a PHP script that says a record already exists and display it to my 16x2 LCD display. I am able to push data to the PHP script and use the data to check whether a record exist or not. If not, a record will be added. Then if a record already exists, I would like my PHP script to send data to the Arduino and use it to display something. But I cannot seem to get how to display "Already Exists!" if my PHP file echoes something it goes right through "Attendance Recorded!".

Here is my PHP file:

```
$res = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE card_id = '$cardID'")or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if (checkAttendance($connect, $row['student_id'])){
        echo "Already Exist!";
    } else {
        recordAttendance($connect, $row['student_id'], $row['guardian_id'], $row['gradeLevel_id'], $row['section_id']);
    }
}
```

Arduino code:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  // Make a HTTP request:
  client.print( "GET /ckcIbed/insertData.php?");
  client.print("uid=");
  client.print( UID );
  client.println( " HTTP/1.1");
  client.print( "Host: " );
  client.println(server);
  client.println( "Connection: close" );
  client.println();
  client.println();
  if (client.available()) {
    lcd.print("Already Exists!");
  } else {
    lcd.print("Attendance Recorded!");
  }
  client.stop();
}
```

Comment: You will have to actually parse the received data. HTTP protocol isn't as simple as you think.

Comment: How should I do it? I've read some way of parsing it but it's not clear for me. Thanks!